# Why can't I call values that inside of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, variables, plugins

Few days after since I started to make the plugin, I wondered what's the difference between these 2 codes and why second code doesn't work.

The first one looks like this:

```
<div class="searching">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

(function($) {
  $.fn.slideInit = function() {
    const myGallery = $(this),
          myList = myGallery.find('li');

    <!-- Log Section -->
    console.log(myList);
    <!----------------->
  };
} (jQuery));
$('.searching').slideInit();
```

This code works fine what I expected. Variable `myGallery` can be defined inside of the code block.

And the second one which doesn't work looks like this:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.slideInit = function() {
    const defaults = {
      myGallery: $(this),
      myList: myGallery.find('li')
    };

    <!-- Log Section -->
    console.log(defaults.myList);
    <!----------------->
  };
} (jQuery));
$('.searching').slideInit();
```

What I've done in this code is just added the variables inside of an object which called `defaults`, but when I run this code, an error pops up:

> index.html:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: myGallery is not defined

I think there's something difference between those 2 codes but couldn't find or figured out by myself.

Would you guys teach me why the `myGallery` that is scoped by the variable `default` can't be defined?

Comment: It should be `defaults.myGallery.find('li')`, or just declare the `$(this)` item outside of `defaults` and use it then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: @darklightcode Even if it's scoped by `defaults` already?

Comment: @calmwave - It isn't. That isn't how scope works in JavaScript, an object initializer ("object literal") doesn't create a new scope. If this isn't a duplicate of the question Jeto points to above, that question and its answers are certainly very close and should help you understand a bit more about this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe I should go to search about scope. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: @calmwave - :-) Very briefly: Only functions, blocks, and parameter lists create new scope. (It was only functions in ES5 and earlier. Blocks only create new scope for `let`, `const`, `class`, and `function` declarations in strict mode. Parameter lists create new scope if you use advanced parameter list features, like default values.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Big respect for detail commenting. Thank you so much and Happy Holiday season :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const defaults = {
  myGallery: $(this),
  myList: myGallery.find('li') // <====
};
```

There is no `myGallery` variable in scope at that point. You can either call `$()` twice, add `myList` after-the-fact, or use a `myGallery` variable:

```
const defaults = {
  myGallery: $(this),
  myList: $(this).find('li')
};
```

or

```
const defaults = {
  myGallery: $(this)
};
defaults.myList = defaults.myGallery.find('li');
```

or

```
const myGallery = $(this);
const defaults = {
  myGallery,
  myList: myGallery.find('li')
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your var outside your literal or reference it using `this`

```js
const defaults = {
      myGallery: "DONALD DUCK",
      myList: function() { console.log(this.myGallery) }
    };
 
 defaults.myList();
```

Comment: I would keep your advice. Thank you :>